# REST API File Upload - Porting Python to PowerShell

Tags: python, powershell

Could anyone help me perform the following Python process in PowerShell?

```
json_res = json.loads(res.text,object_pairs_hook=collections.OrderedDict)
files = {'file':open(image_path,'rb').read()}
_data = json_res.items()
_data[1] = ('upload_params',_data[1][1].items())
upload_file_response = requests.post(json_res['upload_url'],data=_data[1][1],files=files,allow_redirects=False)
```

Here is my PowerShell to get the initial json response used in the json_res object using:

```
$initialization_parameters = @{
  "name" = $($image.Name);
  "size" = $($image.Length);
  "content_type" = $(if ($image.Extension -match 'jp*g') { "image/jpeg" } elseif ($image.Extension -match 'png') { "image/png" } elseif ($image.Extension -match 'gif') { "image/gif" } else { "image/jpeg" });
  "parent_folder_path" = "profile pictures";
  "as_user_id" = $("sis_user_id:" + $file_id) 
}

$initialization_parameters = $initialization_parameters | ConvertTo-Json

$initial_response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $avatars_base_url -Headers $headers -Body $initialization_parameters -ContentType "application/json" -Method POST
```

I am not sure how to do the next request though and add the image for upload - I have tried sending a byte array OR just the local file path, but those don't seem to work.

Specifically, I would like to know how to best mimic the 2nd and 5th lines of the Python code I have there in PowerShell.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need to do. If not, hopefully it will at least put you on the right track...

```
$FileContent = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($Image.FullName)
$UploadInfo @{
    "File" = $Image.Name
    "Data" = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($FileContent)
}
$FileUpload = Invoke-JSONMethod -uri $Upload_URL -ContentType "application/json" -Method POST -Body (ConvertTo-Json $UploadInfo) -AcceptType "application/json"
```

Comment: I don't think that will do it - I think I need to do a multipart method as I always the error (412) Precondition Failed

Unfortunately, I do not know how to do a multi part method in PowerShell.